# How to get games working on MAME?

Tags: mame

I want to play a certain game (Raiden 2) using MAME. I think this is possible, because there are videos on youtube of people who claim to have done this.

What general process should I follow to get a game working on MAME?

For example, should I choose an emulator, then choose a compatible romset?
Or should I choose a romset, then choose a compatible emulator?
Or something else?

Opinions on the Internet differ, and the MAME and retropie documentation are sadly ambiguous.

Also, what criteria should I use to choose emulators and/or romsets?
Is there a way to discover which romset(s) and/or emulator(s) are more likely to result in a working Raiden II than others, like some sort of compatibility matrix?

I found this web page, which may be relevant somehow:

http://adb.arcadeitalia.net/dettaglio_mame.php?game_name=raiden2&arcade_only=0&autosearch=1

Comment: Once I have a working procedure to get any games at all working with MAME, my intention is to fix the MAME and retropie documentation to document the process, then validate the process documentation by attempting to get a second game working.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The question is about using MAME. It is a modern emulator software running on modern computer systems and equipped with manuals and support forums.

Comment: @justme The first step for a lot of people doing retro computing is to get a modern emulator working. How does it look if we are too stuck up our own arses to help people even get started with retro computing?

Comment: @JeremyP That does not change the fact that questions how to configure and how to use modern emulators to run old games is specifically listed as off topic in the current rules of what questions to avoid on RC.SE. That's because the emulator itself isn't retro, and has manuals, setup guides, active discussion forums for support etc. If you think these kind of questions should be on topic here, you need to suggest a change in the rules.

Comment: @JeremyP The first step for a lot of people doing retro computing is to get a modern computer working. How does it look if we are too stuck up our own arses to help people even get started with computing? So let' accept Windows 11 install questions :)) Serious, main point here ist that this question is not one about anything retro, but modern software on modern computers. Even more an extreme widespread one with excelent documentation and user (to user) support at it's source as well as in countless places around he net.

Comment: @Raffzahn Stop twisting my words. There's a difference between getting a modern operating system working and getting an application designed to do retro computing working. The question is about retro, it's about getting to the point of being able to do retro computing.

Comment: @JeremyP Not twisting, just extending it right the line you present. Or would you deny that computer and OS setup as basic steps to get there as installing MAME? And they bear no difference in what they are about: Modern developments fully outside of RC.SE scope. The agreed RC.SE approach to take is to ask yourself if the same issue will come up when using the classic system. It not, some strong points are needed to make it on topic.

Comment: @Raffzahn I didn't ask you to extend it and it isn't a legitimate extension anyway. MAME is a software product clearly designed to allow people to emulate old (retro) machines. Windows is a general purpose operating system .Your extension is a fallacy. The current RC policy is wrong. It's bullshit in fact. It makes us look like pompous twats.

Comment: @JeremyP Oh, am I only allowed to comment if asked by yours? Like Windows, so is MAME a general purpose system. No difference here. But logic aside, your 'clear' words do show that you would like to have a different site than agreed on. It as discussed long and many times. Today's handling is a common ground found to work independent of individual judgement. Pushing against on question isn't exactly the right place if reopening the issue is your concern. (And no, being serious about site and community isn't in any way being a 'twat').

Answer (score 1):

Just get the latest release of MAME (at the time of writing that's 0.258, soon there should be 0.259) and the romset corresponding to that release, and everything (every rom from a romset) should be loadable.

The idea underneath is that MAME keeps hashes of each rom image inside itself, so it will load only supported romset. However, the majority of roms does not change between MAME releases, so with the high probability, your rom, taken from not very outdated romset, will work with the latest release.

Comment: There are many forks of MAME When you say latest, which do you mean? None of the (many) combinations of emulator and ROM I've tried so far works. There are several different failure modes.